# Regex: Count differences between two strings

Tags: regex, string

Say I have two strings, `Hello` and `heddo`, how can I create a Regex to match difference between them?

For example in my case there are three differences, `H` is now lowercase `h`, and twice `l` is now `d`.

Or `Hello` and `Text` has three differences, `T` `X` and `T`

Thank you

Comment: Why the letter e of word Hello and Text is considered as difference?

Comment: IMHO this can't be done in a single regex. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: With regex this cann't be done, searches for edit distance or alignment algorithms

Comment: What does this have to do with regexes? At their core, regexes are a convenient notation for describing (possibly infinite) sets of strings, or for describing search patterns (*does string S match pattern P?*).

Comment: `Hello` and `Text` have a similar character `e` , so differences are `T`, `x` and `t` @Luke

Comment: Regex is not best way, but some how can be done @JoseRicardoBustosM.

Comment: I think it was a mistake to say mention Regex in the title when really I am looking to solve a problem - I see now the Regex is not going to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not something you should do with Regexes (unless you have a good reason for that ?). Here is a solution in Python, for example.

```
def count_diff(a,b):
    return sum(x!=y for x,y in zip(a,b))

print(count_diff('Hello', 'hebdo'))
```

You can try it [here](https://repl.it/FvCF).

Comment: What would be the .NET Linq equivalent of this?

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien no idea. Maybe the topic of a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Regex for `Hello` is:

```
 ^((H)|.)?((e)|.)?((l)|.)?((l)|.)?((o)|.)?$
```

Where even index is equal to next (odd) item, this character is matched.

```
 Match 1
 Full match 0-5 `Hello`
 Group 1.   0-1 `H`
 Group 2.   0-1 `H`
 Group 3.   1-2 `e`
 Group 4.   1-2 `e`
 Group 5.   2-3 `l`
 Group 6.   2-3 `l`
 Group 7.   3-4 `l`
 Group 8.   3-4 `l`
 Group 9.   4-5 `o`
 Group 10.  4-5 `o`

 Full match 0-5 `Heddo`
 Group 1.   0-1 `H`
 Group 2.   0-1 `H`
 Group 3.   1-2 `e`
 Group 4.   1-2 `e`
 Group 5.   2-5 `ddo`
 Group 7.   5-5 ``
 Group 9.   5-5 ``
```

Or Check odd items, Group2,4,6,8 `!= null` -> matched

If this REGEX and results are acceptable, let me know and write script for this.

Create Desire Regex:

```js
var word = "Hello" ;
var myregex = '^' ;
for(i=0;i<word.length;i++){
 myregex += '(('+word.substr(i,1)+')|.)?';
}
myregex += '$';

// Use Regex to find matched Characters and Differences:

var mymatch = "Heddo".match(new RegExp(myregex)) ;
mymatch.splice(0,1);
var mismatches = 0 ;
var chars = [];
for(i=1;i<mymatch.length;i+=2){
 if(mymatch[i]!==undefined){
     chars.push(mymatch[i]) ;
    }else{
     mismatches++
    }
}
console.log(mismatches); //Count
```